# Stack , Assembly, parameters

Tags: assembly, stack

I have a function with unknown number of parameters.
I tried to do it through C and it didn't work.

I need to count how many they are.
I assume it will be possible with the stack.
so how do I count them..??

thanks

Comment: From the tag wiki of the [tag:assembly] tag: "Also specify the processor or instruction set your question is related to as well as what assembler you are using."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "unknown number of parameters" you mean something like this:

```
void some_function(int first_arg, ...);
```

The clear answer is: In this case it is **not** possible to get the number of parameters.

Some versions of GCC will not "push" the arguments on the stack but reserve some stack memory and then write the arguments to xxx(%ESP).

In this case the following code:

```
printf("%u, %u, %u, %u\n", 1, 2, 3, 4);
printf("%u, %u, %u, %u\n", 1);
```

Will result in two exaclty identical calls of "printf" (because the numbers 2, 3 and 4 are still on the stack).

Comment: I getting an unkown number of Strings to my function and I need to find out how many I got and insert every string to an array cell 
thanks!